# GAE/J - which TLS version is being used?

Tags: google-app-engine, tls1.2

I wonder which TLS version does GAE/J is using?

It's very important for me since we use OAuth2 and TLS 1.0 is no longer supported, thus we want to make sure we use TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2.

In addition, do you know if you can pass JVM params to GAE/J? I know that they use Java7 and if possible we could add these JVM params to enable TLS1.1/1.2

> -Ddeployment.security.SSLv2Hello=false -Ddeployment.security.SSLv3=false -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1=false -D\
>   deployment.security.TLSv1.1=true -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true

**Update**

I added the following code to use TLS 1.1/1.2 (instead of using JVM params)

```
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                    SSLContexts.custom().useTLS().build(),
                    new String[] {"TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"},
                    null,
                    SSLConnectionSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(sf)
                    .build();

            HttpClient  httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(sf)
                    .build();
```

Comment: I don't think this JVM options can make any effect, because you aren't connection from JVM directly, but through a "proxy" service _URL Fetch_

Comment: Hi @IgorArtamonov  , do you know which TLS version does URL Fetch support?